# Get value of cell after a row with specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was thinking of an easier way to extract the data that I need by using an excel formula. For example,

```
A1 = #Fruit
A2 = Apple
A3 = Dog
A4 = Cat
A5 = #
A6 = Sun
A7 = Moon
```

What I want to do is get the value of the cell after the cell having a pound sign (#). In this example, that would be Apple and Sun. Can you help on the formula that should be used to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get Cells Below Matches

```
=LET(data,A1:A9,Char,"#",
FILTER(DROP(VSTACK(data,""),1),
    LEFT(data,1)=Char))
```

[image]

Comment: One character less --> `=LET(data,A1:A9,Char,"#",
FILTER(DROP(VSTACK(data,""),1),
    LEFT(data)=Char))`  --> `LEFT()` only takes first values leaves out rest when not mentioned abt `[num_chars]` (+)

Answer (score 1):

I know am late but here is an alternative:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=LET(x,A1:A9,INDEX(x,TOCOL(XMATCH(LEFT(x),"#")*ROW(x)+1,3)))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=LET(x,A1:A9,CHOOSEROWS(x,TOCOL(ROW(x)/(LEFT(x)="#"),3)+1))
```

---